# How do you pronounce (r) in British English?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

For example, we have 
- car  /kɑː(r)/
- or  /ɔː(r)/

I thought the brackets means you delete it - i.e. non rhotic - but now I see the phonetic spelling of words like "hard" which don't include the r at all /ˈhɑːd/

Comment: This notation is not standard. I would guess that in whatever dictionary you're looking at, /kɑː(r)/ means the /r/ is only pronounced if the word is followed by a vowel. Since the /r/ in *hard* is never followed by a vowel, it's never pronounced and so not included in the phonetic notation.

Comment: There are many accents in British English. You need to be more specific.

Comment: When I listen to the folks on BBC they pronounce their Rs more distinctly than the folks on "This Old House" from the Boston area.

Answer (score 3):

There is a basic rule for the pronunciation of /r/ in non-rhotic varieties of English, for example Southern Standard British English. We only pronounce /r/ if it precedes a vowel sound (sounds, not letters are the important factor). So in standard British English we see the following:

- kærət (carrot)
- rəʊd (road)
- pa:k (park)

In the words above we see orthographic, written, 'R' followed by vowel sounds in *carrot* and *road* and so it is pronounced in these words. In *park*, however, 'R' is followed by the consonant /k/, and so is not pronounced. Notice that if an 'R' is followed by silence it isn't followed by a vowel and is therefore not pronounced. Also notice that the following vowel can be in a completely different word. So we see the following types of pronunciations:

- kɑ: (car)
- kɑ: pɑ:k (car park)
- kɑ:r əlɑ:m (car alarm)

In the first example, there is no following vowel, so we don't pronounce the 'R' in *car*. In the second, the 'R' in *car* is followed by the consonant /p/, so again we don't pronounce it. In the third example this 'R' is followed by the first vowel in the word *alarm* and so this 'R' is pronounced /kɑ:**r** əlɑ:m/.

Lastly notice that written vowels are not important. So in the word weren't, we find:

- wɜ:nʔ (weren't)

The last 'E' in *weren't* is, of course, silent. So the sound following the orthographic 'R' is the consonant, /n/. Because of this we do not pronounce the 'R' here.

Comment: Shouldn't it be /wəːnt/ (B.E.)? Also, isn't /ʔ/ mainly specific to AE?

Comment: @black Certainly not. Pronouncing /t/ as a glottal stop is far more widespread in many British dialects than in any American dialects (e.g., _hit it off_, in which more or all American dialects would reduce the first /t/ to [ɾ], and the second to either [ɾ] or [ʔ], but very rarely both; many Brits, on the other hand, would reduce both to [ʔ]). Some British speakers would pronounce a [t] in _weren’t_, others wouldn’t.

Comment: @black Actually, in negative contractions in SSBE we regularly see three different possibilities for the /t/. It can be realised as /t/, as a /ʔ/ or it can be dropped altogether. We also see free variation with individual speakers, so any particular individual might say /wəːnt/, /wɜːnʔ/ or /wɜːn/ at different times. In terms of frequency in SSBE, by the most common is /wɜːnʔ/ which is the realisation a vast majority of the time. The second most common is without any form of /t/ at all: /wːn/. By far the least common is with a canonical /t/: /wɜːnt/. All three are perfectly fine though! :)

Comment: @Araucaria You seem to have left out a vowel there (and inexplicably gone from [ə] to [ɜ], or the other way around). You also forgot the fourth and also very common option: [wɜ̃ː(ʔ)], where the /t/ is either a glottal stop or dropped altogether, and the /n/ is subsumed into the preceding vowel as a nasalisation.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Yes, I liked Black's proper length marks and so copied his word without noticing that he's using the  Upton transcription scheme (presumably) which uses ə: instead of ɜ:. Then I started editing it and it timed out on me! Yes, that's also a frequent realisation but can't be generalised out to *mustn't* for example, so I kinda hoped that would be subsumed by the general /ʔ/, cos I was focussing most on what happens to /t/ in neg contractions. But that's definitely true re nasalised vowel before glottal. Your diacritics aren't coming through. Don't know if that's my computer?