# Clarification on the rules for pronouncing R in British English

Tags: received-pronunciation

Some rules have been given [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237903/how-do-you-pronounce-r-in-british-english/237950#237950), but I am seeking for a particular clarification.

According to the cited answer, R wouldn't be pronounced in WHERE and ARE
(because the final E is unvoiced, so the words are as if ending with R)

But what about the sentence WHERE ARE YOU GOING ?
The first R(E) is followed by the vowel A, and the second R(E) is followed by the vowel **sound** U.

My precise question is: which of the two R's, if any, would be pronounced ?

Comment: This has some overlap with the following question: [I have a Linking r question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428114)

Comment: Sorry, but this is specifically addressed in the exact answer that you quote in the first line of your question (I’ve voted to close this question as a duplicate of the other one for that reason): before a vowel sound, /r/ is pronounced, otherwise it’s not. The only thing that you’re missing here is that _you_ does **not** begin with a vowel sound. It does not begin with the vowel sound /u/ (which is the one found in _ooze_), but with the consonant sound /j/. It is pronounced /juː/.